# Matrix of a movement

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have a 2D movement given by the initial points $A_i =(0,1)$ and $B_i =(1,1)$, and their final coordinates are $A_f =(\frac{1-\sqrt{3}}{2} , \frac{1-\sqrt{3}}{2})$, and $B_f =(\frac{2-\sqrt{3}}{2} , \frac12)$. The question is to write the (3x3) matrix of this movement.

I've been scratching my head for a while trying to figure out how to get a matrix from the initial coordinates and the final coordinates of 2 points, but I've came out blank. If anyone can help me with this I would really appreciate it.

Comment: See [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix#Affine_transformations) on using homogeneous coordinates to represent affine transformations with $3\times 3$ matrices.

Comment: Two point pairs is not enough to determine an affine transformation uniquely. If there are no other constraints, then a simple approach is to find a _linear_ transformation that satisfies the given constraint (hint: think of it as a change of basis) and embed that into a $3\times3$ matrix. If you take advantage of linearity you can pretty much write it down directly. Alternatively, decide on some combination of simple transformations that are easy to compute, such as a rotation followed by a scaling followed by a translation, construct the individual matrices and multiply them.

Comment: for the moment we have been mostly working with rotation and translation matrices, so i'm pretty sure it will be either one of the two or both.
thanks for answering, i at least know the path i need to take to solve questions like these from now on

Answer (score 1):

You do not need a $3\times 3 $ matrix for this transformation. The following $2\times 2$ matrix will do.

$$ A= \begin {bmatrix}\frac {1}{2}& \frac {1-\sqrt 3}{2}\\\frac {\sqrt 3}{2} &\frac {1-\sqrt 3}{2}\end {bmatrix}$$

Note that the columns of $A$ are the image of the standard unit basis of $R^2$